# Concatenating row values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following 2 tables

```
Table1 ( ID, val1, val2)
Table2 ( ID, val3, val4)
```

this is the condition table1.val1 = table2.val3

For each table1.val1 there can be multiple rows in table2.

If I am joining as following then there will be multiple select for the same table1 values.

```
select t1.*,t2.val4
from table1 t1, table t2
where t1.val1 = t2.val3


0, 1, 2, 4
0, 1, 2, 5
0, 1, 2, 6
```

and so on.

I want to contact all the val4 of table2 as following

```
0, 1, 2, "4/5/6"
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working with? Please read the instructions in the [Sql-Server tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: I typed "Concatenating row values in SQL" into an internet search and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv) was the first in the search results.

Comment: Concatenating strings is server specific, PostgreSQL, for instance, uses `||`, others can differ, though, some have a `CONCAT` function for.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've shown I would suggest using `STRING_AGG` with `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.val1, t1.val2, STRING_AGG(t2.val4, '/')
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.val1 = t2.val3
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.val1, t1.val2
```

Answer (score 0):

select t1.*,Value4=stuff(select  ',' + val4 from table2 t2 where  t1.val1 = t2.val3 for xml path(''),type).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
from table1 t1